# Make gmail AUTH SMTP smart relay by tweaking sendmail.cf (not .mc)

Tags: sendmail

How do I tweak sendmail.cf directly (without going through m4 or .mc 
files) to make gmail (with SMTP AUTH) my smart relay? Notes:

- With Comcast, I just put "DSsmtp.comcast.net" in sendmail.cf, 
  since they authenticate by IP, and don't require "SMTP AUTH"
- I'm now w/ Qwest, and want to use gmail's SMTP AUTH server. I 
  realize I could use smtp.q.com, but prefer gmail's.
- I've confirmed I can send email using gmail's server:

```
    > openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
    CONNECTED(00000003)

    [... lots of certificate stuff ...]

    220 mx.google.com ESMTP y7sm198769pbg.43 
    ehlo 
    250-mx.google.com at your service, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 
    250-SIZE 35882577 
    250-8BITMIME 
    250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH 
    250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
    auth plain AGNhcnRlci5iYXJyeQxxxxxxxxxx 
    235 2.7.0 Accepted 
    mail from:  
    250 2.1.0 OK y7sm198769pbg.43 
    rcpt to:  
    250 2.1.5 OK y7sm198769pbg.43 
    data 
    354  Go ahead y7sm198769pbg.43 
    Subject: Hi there 

    End of message 

    QUIT 
    DONE
```

- Based on the above, the sendmail changes I need are:

  - connect on port 465, not port 25 (although port 25 w/ STARTTLS 
    also works)
  - connect using SSL
  - Send "auth plain AGNhcnRlci5iYXJyeQxxxxxxxxxx" after ehlo and 
    before rcpt.
- I know that tweaking the mc file and running m4 is the correct way 
  to do this, but my .cf file is hand-customized and quite fragile, so 
  I'm hoping to avoid that.
- I realize I could have sendmail deliver to localhost:26 and have a 
  Perl script running there that relays to smtp.gmail.com:465 using 
  openssl (and passes data as is, except for the "AUTH PLAIN" line), 
  but this seems ugly.

Other solutions appreciated. EG, if anyone knows of a free open relay...

Comment: Why do you want to directly edit the .cf ? Have you lost the .mc and cannot recreate it?

Comment: That's correct. I've edited sendmail.cf by hand quite a lot, so the mc file I have is not even close to the cf file.

Comment: If you've documented your edits, it is possible that one can produce a working .mc that does what you want.

Comment: I haven't (this sendmail.cf file started in 1997), but that is an idea... try to recreate my sendmail.cf by tweaking foo.mc until the resulting foo.cf matches. I may try this or just find a non-free-but-cheap POP-before-SMTP server I can use.

Comment: Hm... http://poprelay.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Is it imperative to use Google's smtp as a relay? If not, maybe [this article](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/) can help.